# How to Check Zxing Library 1.6 or 1.7?

Tags: android, zxing

I have integrated Zxing library in my Android application, and it is Perfectly working, but i am confused about the Version.

How to Check its Version, or on which basis can i identify its Version.

Comment: is there any good reason to check Version of Zxing in your Application?

Comment: Yea my Requirement is 1.7 that's Y, i want to check.

Comment: you have integrate library then  should have known which Zxing you used.

Comment: @Herry: Yea i have integrated but i haven't seen its Version Anywhere, and made build.xml file.

Comment: @you should have to close Question.

Comment: @Herry : Why do you want to close this question, it is about old version, but it is a programming related question.

Comment: Just give one good reason why you want Zxing Version you have used in Application.you should follow Sean Answer.Just used Library which available in Zxing Project .

Comment: @Herry: I want to write Its Description in the Project Documents. That is the Reason. And if you don't have Any Answer no need to Discuss More.

Comment: In my case, I didn't integrate the zxing myself but now I am assigned to see if there is any newer version which can make scanning faster and accurate. Please let me know how I can find the current version from the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question doesn't make sense. What version did you integrate? That's your answer.

If you are using it as a library, go download 1.7 from http://code.google.com/p/zxing and use that if you must. If you modified the code into yours, then you're not really using an official release of our project anyway, so again doesn't quite make sense.

You should be using 2.0 anyway. 1.7 is quite old.

Comment: It's nice to known Zxing is updated to 2.0.Can you just point out what Major Enhancement you have added in Zxing 2.0. Specially in Android Client.

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from using the Android client as a library, if that's what you're doing. It's not a library and we do not like copying of the whole app. I will not help you.

Comment: Sorry may be you get my comment in wrong way ,we are not using Copying that whole App.